# Getting Unable to find a specification for while installing pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'testprofile' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testprofile
  pod 'AppAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/GemHQ/react-native-app-auth.git', :branch => 'master', :tag => 'v2.4.0'

  target 'testprofile-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'testprofileTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

# end
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'DCTAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/danielctull/DCTAuth.git'
```

I am keep getting `[!] Unable to find a specification for 'AppAuth'.` when i run `pod install`

I tried many things but the error doesn't go away. I don't know what is an issue here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use "pod 'AppAuth' "  Only instead of  " pod 'AppAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/GemHQ/react-native-app-auth.git', :branch => 'master', :tag => 'v2.4.0' "

Comment: @hussnainahmad but I want to point to that particular git repo which is actually fork of `AppAuth`

Comment: can please Share link from where you have got this pod?

Comment: i think you are mixing pod with cartage..